# Wordpress update feature

Tags: wordpress

I am running wordpress on two domains on the same machine.
For one domain that I had for longer, updates and downloads process automatically.
On the other domain folder, wordpress asks me for a ftp account. Why is that? 
Can I copy the connection information from the working WP to the not working one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worpdress asks you for FTP credentials when it cannot access your plugin directory directly. Your php runs as apache user but plugin directory owned by another user. If you do not want to enter ftp credentials again and again, you can define ;

```
define( 'FTP_USER', 'user' );
define( 'FTP_PASS', 'pass' );
define( 'FTP_HOST', 'ftp.your_site.com:21' );
```

in `wp-config.php`

Comment: You were right, the folders were not owned by the right user. However, I still seeing the same FTP input field. It's funny because the other page is running without that / I dont remember specifying it. Do you by any chance know which file from the working installation to copy into the not working install?

Comment: However, change your wp files permissions recursively to php user. For example, change owner with www-data